# How to render a partial view in MVC with filtering and paging

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I took my first step into MVC. I'm trying to make my personal Wallpaper-Gallery.

So I made a [Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KoRu.jpg) of what I want to achieve.

As of today I'm searching the web for about three days to get this thing done. But I'm having problems with filtering and paging, so I hope here's someone who can help me.

This is what I have so far:

**View**

```
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@model PagedList.IPagedList<WallpaperGalleryWeb.Wallpaper>

<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<style type="text/css">
    .thumbnail {
        width: 200px;
        height: 112px;
        margin: 5px;
        float: left;
    }

        .thumbnail img {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
</style>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="thumbnail" onclick="">
        <a href="~/Wallpapers/Details/@item.ID" style="display: block; height: 100%">
            <img src="~/File/Thumbnail/@item.ID">
        </a>
    </div>
}

<br clear="all" />
<br />

Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
```

**Controller**

```
public class WallpapersController : DatabaseController
{
    // GET: Wallpapers
    public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
       return PartialView(db.Wallpapers.Include(i => i.Author)
                                 .Include(i => i.Orientation)
                                 .Include(i => i.Set)
                                 .Include(i => i.Source)
                                 .Include(i => i.Category)
                                 .OrderBy(x => x.ID)
                                 .ToPagedList((page ?? 1), 100));
    }

    // GET: Wallpapers/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Wallpaper wallpaper = db.Wallpapers.Find(id);
        if (wallpaper == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(wallpaper);
    }
}
```

So my question at this point is: How do I get a static layout (I know how to by CSS) with dropdownlists for filtering/sorting and pass the selected values, combined with paging functionality, to the controller to refresh ONLY the "Result Area" with the items from the controller?

Greetings!

Comment: Unrelated to your question, the SQL query generated within your `Index` method is going to be atrocious. You'd be far better served by using a `.Select()` and retrieving either a model, or anonymous object with only the properties you want. Most likely, you won't need every property on 6 objects.

Comment: Use AJAX. Do your research and give it a go. Then, come back with a specific question, if you run into any difficulties. As it is, your question is too broad.